# Can't run Nexmo API using EasyPHP

Tags: api, easyphp, vonage

I'm using EasyPHP on my computer as my localweb.
I'm trying to use pre-built PHP code to use Nexmo API available at https://github.com/prawnsalad/Nexmo-PHP-lib

But when I try to send sms, I get this error:
Cannot display an overview of this response

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply Try to change

```
var $nx_uri = 'https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json';
```

to

```
var $nx_uri = 'http://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json';
```

(without s).

Comment: We would suggest you use SSL when in production

Answer (score 0):

First can you enable error reporting:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_error', 1);
?>
```

Secondly

Can you check if you have either CURL or allow_url_fopen are enabled? You can create a phpinfo() file `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`.

EDIT:

Can you change your code to

```
<?php
include "NexmoMessage.php";
$nexmo_sms = new NexmoMessage('api_key', 'api_secret');
$info = $nexmo_sms->sendText( '+447234567890', 'MyApp', 'Hello!' );

var_dump($info);
?>
```

Then rebun your test and feedback.

Thanks,

Kyle,
Nexmo Developer and Helpdesk

Comment: My phpinfo are as this: cURL support: enabled / allow_url_fopen: On. The result is the same. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Yes, But there is no change in output. The output page source is: <p>Cannot display an overview of this response</p>

Comment: bool(false), means 1 of the two checks has failed. try echoing and see where you are failing, starting on line 75 and ending on line 85 in NexmoMessage.php

Comment: Do you mean these checks?: // Making sure strings are UTF-8 encoded // Make sure $from is valid // URL Encode? These are on 75-85. I think I have no problem with these. I'm trying to send a very simple massage. I uploaded my codes to a real hosting and they work fine. I only have problem with EasyPHP on my computer.

Comment: I can find the error, but I don't know how to fix this: Warning: file_get_contents(https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\wamp\www\anbooh\NexmoMessage.php on line 184, I must mention that CURL and allow_url_fopen are both enabled.